# "Illegal Instruction (core dumped)" lubuntu 17.10 on development software (node, npm, sublime text)

Tags: lubuntu, nodejs, sublime-text, npm

I am running a old machine with ubuntu 17.10 installed, on an old AMD Athlon XP 19000+ with 1,5Gb RAM.
When trying to use some development applications in the terminal, like:

- node (NodeJS)
- npm (Node Package Manager)
- subl (Sublime Text)

But in response I'm getting a lot of this messages **"Illegal Instruction (core dumped)"**, and I can not use them.
Running Sublime Text in the GUI also does not work, it crashes.

I have tried reinstalling the OS and again the applications, a the some thing happens.

What is going on? This is a Operation system problem? A application Problem? An Hardware Problem? Any Solution?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happens because your processor lacks the SSE2 instruction set. There's nothing you can do about it other than buying a new, more modern processor. I'm actually experiencing the same thing with my Athlon XP 2500+. The best solution is to use a distribution aimed at processors like this. I'm personally using antix Linux 17, which has its repositories aimed at non-SSE2 processors.

There's some things you can try as workarounds for some programs, but you will be out of luck for others. You can try to compile from source yourself, this will ensure the processors instructions are tailored for your specific processor, as its the one compiling it. I used this approach for RetroArch and worked flawlessly. You could also try to use older versions of the software you want to run that didn't require SSE2. Firefox for instance began using SSE2 in version 48, so you can use that version for a browser. However I personally use Pale Moon, a browser based on Firefox that has a dedicated non-SSE2 build. It can be found on the antix repositories. The main drawback is that you won't be able to use extensions as they require newer versions of the browser.

So now you know. Whenever you see "Illegal Instruction" it means that your processor doesn't understand what it's being told to do, since it doesn't have the required "dictionary", if you will, to understand it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that was a good response (to my knowledge). I understood the problem that I'm facing now and some possible solutions. Thanks once again.